# How to remove everything except first column of text in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Basically I have a list of IP's and ports at the end, ex:

```
85.39.138.58 151
187.39.55.23 399
80.14.5.209 1424
80.14.6.217 1424
1.1.135.73 1464
80.14.5.209 135
80.14.7.2 1392
187.39.55.100 399
67.78.18.222 1472
```

How would I go about removing the ports from the list so it looks like this:

```
85.39.138.58
187.39.55.23
80.14.5.209
80.14.6.217
1.1.135.73
80.14.5.209
80.14.7.2
187.39.55.100
67.78.18.222
```

Answer (score 1):

Find what: `([\d.]+) \d+$`

Replace with: `$1`

Select regular expression

Replace all

Or, to be more precise, use `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) \d+$`

I'm surprised about this, but adding `^` at the start of either of these makes them not-work. I'm not that familiar with Notepad++'s regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `([^ ]+) .+` with `\1`, in regex mode:

[image: screen shot]

An alternative would be to use a macro, which I sometimes find easier.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to start/stop recording, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to play.

So you could do something like:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Then either hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> until you get to the end of the file, or do Macro -> Run multiple times -> Run until end of file.

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `\b((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(.*)`

Replace with: `\1`

Check Regular expression

Replace all

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

Find what: `\s+\d+$`
Replace with: `nothing`

Check `Regular expression`
Click on `Replace all`

This will remove the port number and the space before it from all the lines.